# A confusing problem with IE7 and styles being applied

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, internet-explorer-7, cross-browser

For the life of me, I can not figure out why some styles are not being applied to an unordered list.

If you view this site: http://www.alclawyers.com.au/ in Firefox, you will notice there are circles down the bottom of the text that can be clicked to shift to different *panels* of content.

Now, when you visit the same site in IE7, none of the styles from the stylesheet are being applied (well at least not for me).

I know a fair bit about selector support, but I can not figure out this one!

If anyone digs in and follows the code, here is what is happening

- jQuery counts panels and makes an unordered list beneath the text.
- CSS styles this list (see Firefox for intended layout).

It's probably something really simple, but it's giving me a lot of grief.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I figured it out already, I have a div being inserted in JS without the closing angle bracket. Was working in FF, but IE tripped up on it.

Thanks to anyone that took the time to investigate!

Comment: was half way through writing that! :)

Comment: Sorry Colin! Much appreciated though that you took the time.

Answer (score 2):

firefox likes to close unclosed tags for you. IE gets a bad wrap lots of times.